# Unable to hit Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate a request signature: null
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:71)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3Signer.sign(S3Signer.java:127)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:652)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.Amazon
```

```html
 s3.setEndpoint("http://aws.amazon.com/s3/");

            /*
             * Create a new S3 bucket - Amazon S3 bucket names are globally unique,
             * so once a bucket name has been taken by any user, you can't create
             * another bucket with that same name.
             *
             * You can optionally specify a location for your bucket if you want to
             * keep your data closer to your applications or users.
             */
            System.out.println("Creating bucket " + bucketName + "\n");
            s3.createBucket(bucketName);
            /*
             * List the buckets in your account
             */
            System.out.println("Listing buckets");
            for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + bucket.getName());
            }
            System.out.println();

            /*
             * Upload an object to your bucket - You can easily upload a file to
             * S3, or upload directly an InputStream if you know the length of
             * the data in the stream. You can also specify your own metadata
             * when uploading to S3, which allows you set a variety of options
             * like content-type and content-encoding, plus additional metadata
             * specific to your applications.
             */
            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, createSampleFile()));

            /*
             * Download an object - When you download an object, you get all of
             * the object's metadata and a stream from which to read the contents.
             * It's important to read the contents of the stream as quickly as
             * possibly since the data is streamed directly from Amazon S3 and your
             * network connection will remain open until you read all the data or
             * close the input stream.
             *
             * GetObjectRequest also supports several other options, including
             * conditional downloading of objects based on modification times,
             * ETags, and selectively downloading a range of an object.
             */
            System.out.println("Downloading an object");
            S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
            displayTextInputStream(object.getObjectContent());

            /*
             * List objects in your bucket by prefix - There are many options for
             * listing the objects in your bucket.  Keep in mind that buckets with
             * many objects might truncate their results when listing their objects,
             * so be sure to check if the returned object listing is truncated, and
             * use the AmazonS3.listNextBatchOfObjects(...) operation to retrieve
             * additional results.
             */
            System.out.println("Listing objects");
            ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucketName)
                    .withPrefix("My"));
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                        "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
            }
            System.out.println();

            /*
             * Delete an object - Unless versioning has been turned on for your bucket,
             * there is no way to undelete an object, so use caution when deleting objects.
             */
            System.out.println("Deleting an object\n");
            s3.deleteObject(bucketName, key);
```

S3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:788)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:713)
        at com.keypoint.examples.amazon.S3Sample.main(S3Sample.java:98)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString(Base64.java:36)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:69)

Comment: Could any one please help on this

Comment: I can't find a question to answer...

Comment: I am getting the following exception while run the above code
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate a request signature: null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Unknown Source)
 at com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString(Base64.java:36)
 at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:69)
 ... 9 more
Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able to access the network.
Error Message: Unable to calculate a request signature: null